# Validation of custom widgets

Tags: python, django

How should validation errors be propagated for custom widgets where the widget input itself may be incoherent? Case in point, I'm creating a custom date input widget for a `Date` field that allows the user to select the date according to the Japanese Imperial calendar. This requires an era dropdown and a year input, and it's perfectly possible to select an era–year combination that is in itself invalid. The widget converts this input to/from a Python `date` object using the `MultiWidget.value_from_datadict`/`MultiWidget.decompress` methods:

```
def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    era, imperial_year, month, day = [widget.value_from_datadict(data, files, f'{name}_{i}')
                                      for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets)]

    try:
        return date(self._j2w.convert(f'{era}{imperial_year}年'), int(month), int(day))
    except ValueError:
        # selected era/year combination was invalid
        return ''
```

All I can do in this method is catch any `ValueError` and return an empty value instead, which means the field's validator complains about *missing* data, not about an incorrect value. If I simply `raise` the `ValueError` or a `ValidationError`, it's causing an uncaught exception error.

Where and how should this kind of validation happen? I'd like the keep the abstraction of the Japanese picker purely inside the UI layer, and keep the backing field a simple `Date` field.

Answer (score 0):

For now I've solved it this way:

*widgets.py*

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms import MultiWidget

class ImperialDateInput(MultiWidget):
    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        try:
            ...
        except ValueError:
            return ValidationError(
                _('Invalid date: %(era)s%(year)s/%(month)s/%(day)s'),
                code='invalid',
                params=dict(era=era, year=imperial_year, month=month, day=day)
            )
```

*fields.py*

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms import DateField
from .widgets import ImperialDateInput

class ImperialDateField(DateField):
    widget = ImperialDateInput

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, ValidationError):
            raise value

        return super().to_python(value)
```

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models
from . import fields

class ImperialDateField(models.DateField):
    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        return super().formfield(form_class=fields.ImperialDateField, **kwargs)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = ImperialDateField()
```

In other words, the widget's `value_from_datadict` does the conversion from custom input elements to a regular `date`, or *returns* an instance of `ValidationError`. That is backed by a special Form Field which recognises this in its `to_python` method, from where it's allowed to `raise` that exception. To bake this right into the model I've also added a custom model field, but that is optional.

Not sure if this is the most elegant way of solving this; it does feel a bit icky.